# 親子関係にあるモデルを同時保存すると、validates: user_id, presence: trueによってロールバックされます。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

以下のようなモデル構造で、下記処理を実行します。

```
tweet = Tweet.create
user = User.new
user.likes.build(tweet_id: tweet.id)
user.save
```

すると"Likes is invalid"となり、ロールバックされます。
build時にuser_idがnilなので、

```
validates :user_id, presence: true
```

に引っかかっているように思います。

モデル、DB構造を変えずに、UserとLikeを同時保存するにはどのような処理が有効でしょうか？

---

#### モデル構造

Userモデル

```
  has_many :likes
  has_many :tweets, through: :likes
end
```

Tweetモデル

```
class Tweet < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes
  has_many :users, through: :likes
end
```

Likeモデル（中間テーブル）

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tweet
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :tweet_id, presence: true
end
```

DB

```
create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "tweet_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
create_table "tweets", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "context"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
tweet = Tweet.create
User.transaction do
  user = User.create!
  user.likes.create!(tweet_id: tweet.id)
end
```

のようにすればバリデーションにひっかからずに作成することが可能です。ここでのポイントは`transaction`メソッドで、これにより別々にモデルを作成・保存してもどちらかが保存に失敗すれば`User`と`Like`はどちらも保存されません。これで実質的な「同時保存」の条件は満たしていると思われます。
また、`transaction`内部で`create!`を使っているのは、このメソッドが保存失敗時に例外を発生させそれがトランザクションを巻き戻させるためです。`create`では例外が発生せずトランザクションが巻き戻らない点にご注意ください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
saveによって一括保存する状態を作り出すことは難しいでしょうか？

Comment: このケースだと、Likeのほうが先に保存されてしまうのは変更できなさそうです。一回のsaveで保存しなくてはいけない特別な理由がない限り、トランザクションを使うのが一番確実だと思います。